# ASP.net and SQL Server 2005: ASPNET account setting

Tags: asp.net

I'm a bit confuse about the ASP.NET account in SQL Server 2005. In my web site connection string, I use `sa` account to connect to the SQL Server database. When I use Firefox to login to my website, I get an error

> Login failed for user: 'AccountName'

I have found the answers on ms support site. It mentioned 3 methods to correct this method and one of them is grant the correct permission in the SQL Server for ASPNET.

I selected public for Server role, permission to connect to the database is granted and login enabled and i also selected the database in the user mapping. I still get the permission error on my database stored procedure.

What am I missing?

Edit: I set `ASPNET` as db owner in my database and everything work. If I just set read and write, it doesn't work. Isn't setting `ASPNET` account to db owner a security risk?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly do not **ever** connect as SA from a web application, that's a huge security risk.

It sounds like your connection string is messed up, that it's using NT authentication rather than the specified user/password combination.

You shouldn't need to set the application pool account to be dbo unless you're directly accessing tables; rather add it to the public group for that database; that way you can limit it properly.